# Datos dinamicos en un aside

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Dentro un sistema de plantillas en un proyecto de Laravel, tenemos la plantilla general. Dentro de ésta, se dispone diferentes parte añadidas como includes o como yield.

Una posible estructura podría ser ésta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces, dentro del layout principal de "public.blade.php", se dispone de un include que llama al "navbar.blade.php" y con `@yield('content')` llamo al contenido de la vista "index.blade.php".

Tanto esta vista como otras vistas del proyecto tienen un SECTION en la parte izquierda y un ASIDE en la parte derecha. El ASIDE se incrusta por medio de un otro include.

[index.blade.php]

```
@extends('layouts.public')

@section('content')

            <section id="content">

                {{-- Datos dinámicos --}}
                <article>
                   ...
                </article>

            </section>

            <!-- Aside -->
            @include('layouts.aside')
            <!-- /.aside -->

@endsection
```

[aside.blade.php]

```
            <aside id="sidebar">

                {{-- Datos dinámicos --}}
                <article>
                   ...
                </article>

            </aside>
```

Lo que deseo es cargar una serie de listados clasificatorios dentro de ese ASIDE que aparecerá en cada una de las vistas de contenido principal.

Por ejemplo, la ruta '/' llama al método de un controlador que pasa datos a la vista de "index.blade.php".

Pero, si se quieren cargar datos dinámicos en el "aside.blade.php" ¿cómo se haría si, en principio no es llamado por una ruta en específico como pasa con el "index.blade.php"? ¿Debería plantear de ota manera el problema?

¿Alguien me puede poner un ejemplo?

Comment: No estoy muy seguro de entender: ¿deseas pasar cierta información a la vista de aside? y asumo que dicha información es distinta en cada «página» del proyecto.

Comment: @Shaz, hola gracias por atender la consulta. Imagina una wiki o un blog y que en la columna derecha, en todas las páginas, se dispone de un mismo listado resumen de las categorías disponibles, top 5 de últimas entradas insertadas, globo de tags de las publicaciones, ... Todo eso dentro de la columna derecha para todas las páginas. Como sería un mismo contenido para todo el sitio, pensaba pasarlo a un include aparte y que la carga de esos datos no dependiera de la propia vista. No sé si me explico más ahora.

Comment: Igual, también, con eso que su contenido, si no en todas las vistas, en casi todas, el include del ASIDE, puede que deba estar más en el layout principal de "public.blade.php" más que en cada vista como la de index. No sé.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que deseas es pasar datos distintos en algunas o todas las rutas a la subvista aside, puedes pasar dichos datos como segundo parámetro en un array, al momento de incluir la vista:

```
@include('layouts.aside', ['myData' => $data])
```

ya en la vista simplemente llamas a dicha variable:

```
{{ $myData }}
```

Documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#including-sub-views

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente, para cargar algo en determinada vista que se va a repetir como un ASIDE dentro de una columna del sitio web, he terminado echando mano de la funcionalidad que ofrece Laravel a través de View Composer.

Resumiendo:

- Dentro de una nueva ruta de directorios "./app/Http/View/Composers" en la estructura de carpetas del proyecto, se crea un nuevo archivo de View Composer con el nombre de "AsideComposer.php".
- El archivo, inicialmente, podría contener este contenido tipo:

  namespace App\Http\View\Composers;

  use App\Post;
  use App\Category;
  use Illuminate\View\View;

  class AsideComposer
  {
      /**
       * Create a new profile composer.
       *
       * @return void
       */
      public function __construct()
      {
          //
      }

  ```
  /**
   * @param  View  $view
   * @return void
   */
  public function compose(View $view)
  {
      //...
  }
  ```
- Una vez configuradas, adecuadamente , las consiguientes consultas, el método de "compose()", podría quedara tal como sigue:

  ```
  /**
   * @param  View  $view
   * @return void
   */
  public function compose(View $view)
  {
      $categories = Category::all();
      $last_top5_posts = Post::take(5)
                          ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
                          ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                          ->get();

      $view->with('aside_data', [
          'categories' => $categories,
          'last_top5_posts' => $last_top5_posts,
      ]);
  }
  ```

Así, cada vez que se cargue este ASIDE por medio de un INCLUDE, la vista que lo contenga no tendrá que ejecutar la misma obtención de registros para el mencionado ASIDE.